# Prove that if $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod m$ then $a\equiv b \pmod m$ or $a\equiv-b \pmod m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod m$ then $a\equiv b \pmod m$ or $a\equiv-b \pmod m%$

since $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod m$

then $m\mid a^2-b^2$ and $a^2-b^2=mc$ for some integer $c$.

I am not really sure where to go from here and was thinking maybe to use contradiction?

Comment: $(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: It's not true, unless $m$ is a prime or the power or an odd prime. (correction - only if $m$ is prime.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Power of odd prime is not enough -- $0^2\equiv 3^2\pmod{9}$, but $0$ and $3$ are neither equal nor opposites modulo $9$.

Comment: Counterexample: $3^2\equiv 7^2 \pmod{8}$

Comment: Whoops, yes. @HenningMakholm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod{m}$ means $m|(a+b)(a+b)$.

It does not mean that $m|a+b$ or $m|a-b$. (This happens only when either $\gcd(m,a+b)=1$ or  $\gcd(m,a-b)=1$).

And hence generally we cannot say $a\equiv b\pmod m$ or $a \equiv -b\pmod m$.

Answer (score 2):

$0^2=2^2 \bmod 4$, but $0\neq 2\bmod 4$ and $0\neq -2\bmod 4$